# PyAudio input-output "wire" with separate streams

Tags: python, callback, pyaudio

I'm trying to do some real time audio processing using python and pyaudio. The problem is that I can not get the input stream working right (callback version). The idea was to:

1. Record 131072 samples (at 48kHz it should be 2.73s), using audio_in() then push the buffer to ain_queue. If the input is 2 channels (stereo) sum it to single channel
2. In main thread do self.ain_queue.get(), then process data
3. Push output data to aout_queue
4. In audio_out get data from aout_queue, play it to speakers. If output is stereo then both speakers will play the same data

While output stream works right, the input stream seems to be completely out of sync with data. Recording times of a buffer are from 3.6s to 5.8s on one sound card (USB) and even about 13s for PCI sound card. Even more confusing is that simple in->out wire as in this example https://gist.github.com/fwaechter/8795472 works OK. Reported cpu load is very small ~0.002 for both streams.

Here is the code (stripped):

```
    import Queue, scipy, numpy, pyaudio

class chrono:

def __init__(self, indev=4, outdev=6, clockt=200, samplerate=48000, buflen=131072, lowpass=10000, highpass=2000):
    self.samplerate = samplerate
    self.buffer_len = buflen
    self.frames_per_buf = 4096
    self.err_cnt1 = 0
    self.err_cnt2 = 0
    self.ain_queue = Queue(maxsize=1000)
    self.aout_queue = Queue(maxsize=1000)
    self.indata = {"dat":scipy.zeros(self.buffer_len, dtype="int16"), "cur_frame": 0, "start_tm": 0.0}
    self.outdata = {"dat":scipy.zeros(self.buffer_len, dtype="int16"), "cur_frame": self.buffer_len, "out_buf2":scipy.zeros(self.frames_per_buf*2, dtype="int16")}

    self.pya = pyaudio.PyAudio()
    printd("chrono.__init__:        Audio devices:")
    for i in range(self.pya.get_device_count()):
        cdev = self.pya.get_device_info_by_index(i)
        printd("chrono.__init__\tDev: %d: Name %s, Input channels %d, Output channels %d, Sample rate %d"%(i,cdev["name"],\
                cdev["maxInputChannels"],cdev["maxOutputChannels"],cdev["defaultSampleRate"]))
    self.auin_channels = self.pya.get_device_info_by_index(indev)["maxInputChannels"]
    self.auout_channels = self.pya.get_device_info_by_index(outdev)["maxOutputChannels"]
    self.pya.is_format_supported(rate=self.samplerate, input_device=indev, input_channels=self.auin_channels, input_format=pyaudio.paInt16)
    self.pya.is_format_supported(rate=self.samplerate, output_device=outdev, output_channels=self.auout_channels, output_format=pyaudio.paInt16)
    self.auin = pyaudio.Stream(PA_manager=self.pya, rate=self.samplerate, channels=self.auin_channels, format=pyaudio.paInt16, input=True, \
            input_device_index=indev, frames_per_buffer=self.frames_per_buf, stream_callback=self.audio_in, start=False)
    self.auout = pyaudio.Stream(PA_manager=self.pya, rate=self.samplerate, channels=self.auout_channels, format=pyaudio.paInt16, output=True, \
            output_device_index=outdev, frames_per_buffer=self.frames_per_buf, stream_callback=self.audio_out, start=False)
    return

def close(self):
    self.auin.stop_stream()
    self.auout.stop_stream()
    self.auin.close()
    self.auout.close()
    self.pya.terminate()
    return

def __del__(self):
    return self.close()


def audio_in(self, data, frame_count, time_info, status):
    self.err_cnt1 += 1
    if (self.auin_channels == 2):
        data = numpy.fromstring(data, dtype="int16")
        self.indata["dat"][self.indata["cur_frame"]:self.indata["cur_frame"]+frame_count] = \
                (data[0::2].astype("int32") + data[1::2]) / 2                           # get mean of both channels
    else:
        self.indata["dat"][self.indata["cur_frame"]:self.indata["cur_frame"]+frame_count] = numpy.fromstring(data, dtype="int16")
    if (self.indata["cur_frame"] == 0):                                         # keep track of time - this is start of buffer
        self.indata["start_tm"] = time_info["input_buffer_adc_time"]
    self.indata["cur_frame"] += frame_count                                         # keep track of data position in buffer
    if (self.indata["cur_frame"] >= self.buffer_len):
        self.indata["cur_frame"] = 0
        self.ain_queue.put((self.indata["dat"].astype("float"), self.indata["start_tm"], time_info["current_time"]))    # put new full buffer into queue
    return(None, pyaudio.paContinue)

def audio_out(self, data, frame_count, time_info, status):
    self.err_cnt2 += 1
    if (self.outdata["cur_frame"] >= self.buffer_len):
        try:
            self.outdata["dat"] = self.aout_queue.get_nowait().astype("int16")
        except:
            return("\0"*frame_count*2*self.auout_channels, pyaudio.paContinue)
        self.outdata["cur_frame"] = 0
        self.aout_queue.task_done()
    if (self.auout_channels == 2):
        samples = self.outdata["dat"][self.outdata["cur_frame"]:self.outdata["cur_frame"]+frame_count]
        self.outdata["out_buf2"][0::2] = samples
        self.outdata["out_buf2"][1::2] = samples
        data = self.outdata["out_buf2"].tostring()
    else:
        data = (self.outdata["dat"][self.outdata["cur_frame"]:self.outdata["cur_frame"]+frame_count]).tostring()
    self.outdata["cur_frame"] += frame_count
    return(data, pyaudio.paContinue)


def go(self, cnt=5):
    self.auin.start_stream()
    self.auout.start_stream()
    while(cnt>0):
        dat = self.ain_queue.get(timeout=15)
        print("rec time %f"%(dat[2]-dat[1]))
        self.aout_queue.put(dat[0])
        cnt -= 1
        print(cnt)
        self.ain_queue.task_done()
    self.auin.stop_stream()
    self.auout.stop_stream()
    return dat
```

Tesing the code is done by:

```
 import chrono.py
 tst = chrono.chrono()
 tst.go(10)
```

I'm working on gentoo Linux, python 2.7, and pyaudio 2.9.
What am I missing here? 
Thanks in advance, Michael Widlok